# How to apply changes to each ViewHolder of a RecyclerView, even those that are not displayed?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView. Each ViewHolder in the RecyclerView contains two elements whose visibility I want to set to GONE, upon calling of a method. What I'm trying to do is to wait for the RecyclerView to finish laying out using recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(), change the visibilities for each item, and then remove the GlobalLayoutListener. Here is a part of my code:

```java
    public void deselectMessages() {
            recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                        recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_selected).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.findViewById(R.id.selected_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
```

What can I do to make this work?

I have thought that maybe I can't modify the ViewHolders which are not currently being displayed. But the problem is that when I scroll to those Views, the elements of those ViewHolders have their visibility set to VISIBLE. If I don't modify the visibilities of views currently not on the screen, when I do scroll to those views, the elements of the ViewHolders will have their visibilities set to VISIBLE. What can I do about this? By the way, I am okay with modifying the visibilities in the xml files through code when the deselectMessages() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that the RecyclerView will return a ViewHolder for a given position. RecyclerView only creates some ViewModels that are enough to fill the RecyclerView and few buffer ones. What you need to do is basically maintain a state object within your Adapter. That adapter can then use this state information to render/update the item according to your need in onBindViewHolder function.

In your case you can keep a HashSet flaggedItems. And keep the position or ID of elements you want to show differently.
If you update this set, make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged in your adapter. Adapter will make sure the items that are updated.
And all your logic to decide how the item should look like should go in onBindViewHolder.